# Not able to click on a input type submit button using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

[image: html confirmar button]

Not sure about why, but maybe it is something like JS or hidden element.

I need to click on "Confirmar" button, but for some reason its not clickable.

This button is into a diferent "block" then the others that I fill in the form.

this the html of this button

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$WpModaisCrm1$ctl03$btnRegistrarProtocolo" value="Confirmar" id="btnRegistrarProtocolo" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" autocomplete="off">
```

the "Cancelar" button html is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$WpModaisCrm1$ctl03$btnCancelarProtocolo" value="Cancelar" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$WpModaisCrm1$ctl03$btnCancelarProtocolo&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl00_WpModaisCrm1_ctl03_btnCancelarProtocolo" class="btn btn-primary button-padding" data-dismiss="modal" autocomplete="off">
```

and there is an hidden element with this HTML

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$WpModaisCrm1$ctl03$btnCarregarUcProtocoloAtendimento" value="" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$WpModaisCrm1$ctl03$btnCarregarUcProtocoloAtendimento&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="btnCarregarUcProtocoloAtendimento" style="display: none" autocomplete="off">
```

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5q4dt.png)

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHxiK.png)

code:

```
confirmar = driver.find_element_by_id("btnRegistrarProtocolo")
print(confirmar.is_enabled()) # return True

print(confirmar.is_displayed()) # return True
print(confirmar.is_selected()) # return False

confirmar.submit() # doesn't work
confirmar.click() # doesn't work
```

`click()` and `submit()` does nothing...

**EDIT**

I also can't reach the "Confirmar" button usign "Tab", only with mouse

Comment: Please add the code you have tried that is not working. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: post the <form> tag, and try/catch the .click() and show exception, if any.

Comment: what doesn't work? does it just not do anything? or are you getting an exception? if it's not doing anything, it seems likely that the form data you are trying to submit is not valid or initialized properly.

Comment: Jortega I'll post here at monday

pcalkins I'll post here at monday, no exception when I try click

crookedleaf Just nothing happens, no exception :(

I also can't reach the "Confirmar" button usign "Tab", only with mouse, not sure if it can help with other ideas

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late here, but this particular issue with interactability - even in the case that an element is found in the DOM as you have found - can propagate because of two issues in my experience; either other JS elements are actually "in the way" with respect to their position in the DOM or you are dealing with unruly element types like an input.

The cure in either case is typically to call directly to JS rather than through Python via execute_script() as such:

```
confirmar = driver.find_element_by_id("btnRegistrarProtocolo")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', confirmar)
```

If you find this doesn't work it will be because there is a multiplicity of elements with the same selector on the page in which case you should locate the element via XPath. You can test this with checking length on find_elements() like this:

```
registrars = driver.find_elements(by='id','btnRegistrarProtocolo')
```

or

```
registrars = driver.find_elements_by_id('btnRegistrarProtocolo')


if len(registrars) > 1:
    print('Wow I might've been clicking the wrong element this whole time!')
```

As a normative standard, I always utilize XPath for locating elements simply because if used correctly it leaves little ambiguity in the way of *what* you are interacting with.

Comment: This is the most concise and updated answer: in my case `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', confirmar)` did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The element with text as **Confirmar** is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#btnRegistrarProtocolo[value='Confirmar']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='btnRegistrarProtocolo' and @value='Confirmar']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Tried both, using Xpath and CSS Selector, but nothing happens, any other idea?

Comment: @PedroRoque Can you replace `click()` with `submit()` for both the locators and retest and let me know the status please?

Comment: No exception appears with .click()

Using submit a "pop up" with the "loading" mensage appears, but the form doesnt give the ccorrect response.

I also can't reach the "Confirmar" button usign "Tab", only with mouse